# CASE expression from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, inner-join, where-clause

I'm trying to write a CASE expression where I look at 2 tables (same DB) to output a 1 or 0 and then SUM that column with some grouping on BRANCH and EVUSERID.

This may be the wrong method altogether for what I'm wanting to achieve so am completely open to suggestions.

EVENT table

```
+--------+----------+-----------+---------------------------+-----------+
| BRANCH | EVUSERID | EVENTTYPE |         REFERENC          | ENQUIRYNO |
+--------+----------+-----------+---------------------------+-----------+
|      1 | cunnc    | SAS       | New Cust - Unknown Source |   1468731 |
|      2 | malce    | SAS       | New Cust - Walk-in        |   1792469 |
|      1 | cunnc    | SAS       | Old Cust - Retention      |    897324 |
|      4 | wardt    | OPT       |                           |    986234 |
|      5 | shera    | OPT       |                           |    576324 |
|      4 | hamzk    | SAS       | Old Cust - Service        |   1238746 |
|      5 | chinc    | SAS       | New Cust - Digital        |    687236 |
+--------+----------+-----------+---------------------------+-----------+
```

SORDER table

```
+-----------+---------+
| ENQUIRYNO | NEWUSED |
+-----------+---------+
|   1468731 | N       |
|   1792469 | N       |
|    897324 | U       |
|    986234 | N       |
|    576324 | U       |
|   1238746 | U       |
|    687236 | U       |
+-----------+---------+
```

My desired output would be

```
+--------+----------+----------------+---------+-------+---------+-----------+---------+-------------+--------------+---------+
| BRANCH | EVUSERID | Unknown Source | Walk-in | Phone | Digital | Retention | Service | New Enquiry | Used Enquiry | Unknown |
+--------+----------+----------------+---------+-------+---------+-----------+---------+-------------+--------------+---------+
|      1 | cunnc    |              1 |       0 |     0 |       0 |         1 |       0 |           1 |            1 |       0 |
|      2 | malce    |              0 |       1 |     0 |       0 |         0 |       0 |           1 |            0 |       0 |
|      4 | hamzk    |              0 |       0 |     0 |       0 |         0 |       1 |           0 |            1 |       0 |
|      5 | chinc    |              0 |       0 |     0 |       1 |         0 |       0 |           0 |            1 |       0 |
+--------+----------+----------------+---------+-------+---------+-----------+---------+-------------+--------------+---------+
```

Where I am so far. All is working as expected until I added my join in

```
SELECT
    E.CM_EV_BRANCH,
    E.CM_EV_EVUSERID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN E.CM_EV_EVENTTYPE = 'SAS' AND E.CM_EV_REFERENC LIKE '%Unknown%' THEN 1 END) AS 'UnknownSource',
    SUM(CASE WHEN E.CM_EV_EVENTTYPE = 'SAS' AND E.CM_EV_REFERENC LIKE '%Walk%' THEN 1 END) AS 'Walk-in',
    SUM(CASE WHEN E.CM_EV_EVENTTYPE = 'SAS' AND E.CM_EV_REFERENC LIKE '%Phone%' THEN 1 END) AS 'Phone',
    SUM(CASE WHEN E.CM_EV_EVENTTYPE = 'SAS' AND E.CM_EV_REFERENC LIKE '%Digital%' THEN 1 END) AS 'Digital',
    SUM(CASE WHEN E.CM_EV_EVENTTYPE = 'SAS' AND E.CM_EV_REFERENC LIKE '%Retention%' THEN 1 END) AS 'Retention',
    SUM(CASE WHEN E.CM_EV_EVENTTYPE = 'SAS' AND E.CM_EV_REFERENC LIKE '%Service%' THEN 1 END) AS 'Service',
    SUM(CASE WHEN E.CM_EV_EVENTTYPE = 'SAS' AND S.VM_SO_NEWUSED = 'N' THEN 1 END) AS 'New Enquiry',
    SUM(CASE WHEN E.CM_EV_EVENTTYPE = 'SAS' AND S.VM_SO_NEWUSED = 'U' THEN 1 END) AS 'Used Enquiry',
    SUM(CASE WHEN E.CM_EV_EVENTTYPE = 'SAS' AND S.VM_SO_NEWUSED <> 'U' AND S.VM_SO_NEWUSED <> 'N' THEN 1 END) AS 'Unknown'


FROM
    Datalake.dbo.CM_01_EVENT E
    LEFT JOIN Datalake.dbo.VM_01_SORDER S ON E.CM_EV_ENQUIRYNO = S.VM_SO_ENQUIRYNO

WHERE
    E.CM_EV_BRANCH <> 0 AND E.CM_EV_DEPTTYPE = 'S'
    
GROUP BY 
    E.CM_EV_BRANCH, E.CM_EV_EVUSERID

/*
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN E.CM_EV_EVENTTYPE = 'SAS' AND E.CM_EV_REFERENC LIKE '%Unknown%' OR E.CM_EV_REFERENC LIKE '%Walk%' OR E.CM_EV_REFERENC LIKE '%Phone%' OR E.CM_EV_REFERENC LIKE '%Digital%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) <> 0
*/

ORDER BY 
    E.CM_EV_BRANCH, E.CM_EV_EVUSERID
```

I've commented out the HAVING clause as that didn't work as desired. There are instances in the DB where an EVUSERID exists for a given branch but doesn't meet the criteria in the CASE expressions. These would display as "0" which whilst is correct, I wasn't interested in seeing during developing the SQL statement.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain how the results are incorrect with the `JOIN`?

Comment: When I added in the join the query doesn't execute. Just stays stuck on "Executing" in SSMS. Finishes instantly without

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a `where` clause: this filters out rows that would have all `0`s, and lets you simplify the `case` expressions in the subquery (since one condition is common to all expressions).

Also: don't use single quotes for column aliases! They are meant for literal strings. Use aliases that do not require quoting - or use square brackets to quote them.

So:

```
SELECT
    E.CM_EV_BRANCH,
    E.CM_EV_EVUSERID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN E.CM_EV_REFERENC LIKE '%Unknown%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS UnknownSource,
    SUM(CASE WHEN E.CM_EV_REFERENC LIKE '%Walk%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Walk_in,
    SUM(CASE WHEN E.CM_EV_REFERENC LIKE '%Phone%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Phone,
    SUM(CASE WHEN E.CM_EV_REFERENC LIKE '%Digital%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Digital,
    SUM(CASE WHEN E.CM_EV_REFERENC LIKE '%Retention%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Retention,
    SUM(CASE WHEN E.CM_EV_REFERENC LIKE '%Service%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Service,
    SUM(CASE WHEN S.VM_SO_NEWUSED = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NewEnquiry,
    SUM(CASE WHEN S.VM_SO_NEWUSED = 'U' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Used Enquiry,
    SUM(S.VM_SO_NEWUSED NOT IN ('U', 'N') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Unknown
FROMDatalake.dbo.CM_01_EVENT E
LEFT JOIN Datalake.dbo.VM_01_SORDER S ON E.CM_EV_ENQUIRYNO = S.VM_SO_ENQUIRYNO
WHERE
    E.CM_EV_BRANCH <> 0 
    AND E.CM_EV_DEPTTYPE = 'S'
    AND E.CM_EV_EVENTTYPE = 'SAS' 
    AND (
        E.CM_EV_REFERENC LIKE '%Unknown%'
        OR E.CM_EV_REFERENC LIKE '%Walk%' 
        OR E.CM_EV_REFERENC LIKE '%Phone%'
        OR E.CM_EV_REFERENC LIKE '%Digital%'
        OR E.CM_EV_REFERENC LIKE '%Retention%'
        OR E.CM_EV_REFERENC LIKE '%Service%' 
    )
GROUP BY E.CM_EV_BRANCH, E.CM_EV_EVUSERID
ORDER BY E.CM_EV_BRANCH, E.CM_EV_EVUSERID
```

Comment: This appears to work just as expected! I'll take a proper look at the results tomorrow.

Thank you so much!